# What happened to Blackfyre and Dark Sister?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

We know that the Targaryens have two Valyrian Steel Blades. And [asoiaf wiki entry](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Valyrian_steel) on Valyrian Steel lists the two blades under those who have unknown fates. Is there any canon where we could at least infer what happened to those two blades? Specifically, when was the last time these blades were seen in the canon, worldbook?

EDIT: Also, do we have reason to believe that there would be a momentous event that at least one of them will be found and the one who wields it will play a big badass role in the fight agains the Others?

Comment: I'd assume if the ASoIaF wiki states their fates are unknown, that there is no hint in the canon about their current whereabouts :)

Comment: I'll have to agree with Andres. I don't remember anything from any of the books published, and wikia says their fates are unknown

Comment: IMHO this should be closed. I see no point in repeating what it says on http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Blackfyre and http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dark_Sister ; anything else is unsubstantiated guesswork.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I disagree. It is a highly interesting topic, and GRRM is known for leaving hints. It might even be that TWOW or the next Dunk & Egg novel gives some clue or proof.

Comment: Reading through the wikipages I see that Blackfyre was a bastard sword, just like Longclaw. Interesting, considering R+L=J.

Comment: @TLP Both those wiki entries contain everything known. Everything else will be pointless speculation, until GRRM gives more information. ["You should only ask practical, answerable questions [...] Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @TLP: That sounds like you're stretching things to the point they break (and then some), with the R+L=J comment.

Comment: @TheHonorableNedStark I don't think so. Unless you have a different definition of "interesting".

Comment: @BCdotWEB This is neither a chatty, nor an open-ended question. The wiki entries only contain what is known, so it is fair to assume that hidden clues might still be available.

Comment: @TLP: Of course I use a different definition of interesting, this is interesting to you, and that is interesting to me. :-)

Comment: @TheHonorableNedStark You don't find it interesting that Jon Snow, who might be Rhaegar's son and heir, could be carrying the same Valyrian sword that has been carried by all the Targaryen kings, including Aegon the Conqueror?

Comment: @TLP if you want to propose a theory that Longclaw is actually Blackfyre in disguise, you'll need some explanation of what happened to that other sword the Mormonts held for 500 years (http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Longclaw) and how & why it would have gone from the Golden Company in the free cities to Bear Island. Personally I think it more likely that there are just two unrelated hand-and-a-half swords

Comment: @user568458 Of course it is more likely, but it would be rather a nice coincidence if it did turn out that Jon carried Blackfyre: The hidden king with the hidden king's sword. We know that Bloodraven carried Dark Sister, and that he worked hard to thwart the Blackfyre rebellion. It is not inconceivable that he hid Blackfyre somewhere. And where better to hide it than in plain sight. As for an explanation? Well, who says Jeor Mormont told the truth to Jon? And would he really give away his family heirloom like that?

Comment: @TLP: Yes, it's a cute idea and quite a poetic and strong hint to the importance of Jon Snow, possibly as a contender to the role of Azor Ahai. But as it's been said, the Mormonts had the sword for a longer period of time, which makes this theory full of holes. Unless, of course, Jeor Mormont knew about the R+L=J theory and gave Jon the Blackfyre, rather than the true Longclaw which is still on Bear Island... :-)

Comment: @TheHonorableNedStark When reading Dunk & Egg, GRRM places a lot of emphasis on the swords. Aegon the Unworthy gave Blackfyre to one of his bastard sons, and people took that to mean he meant for him to be king. I seem to recall that in *The Mystery Knight*, where a Blackfyre pretender appeared, there was talk that he "should have" the sword.

Comment: @gelolopez Do you mean will any of the swords have a connection to Lightbringer and/or Azor Ahai?

Answer (score 5):

The most probable answer is that **[Blackfyre](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Blackfyre)** is with the [Golden Company](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Golden_Company) (given its roots with [Aegor "Bittersteel" Rivers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegor_Rivers)).

**[Dark Sister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dark_Sister)** is either at [Summerhall](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Summerhall) (may have been confiscated from [Brynden "Bloodraven" Rivers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers) when he was banished) or be somewhere at [The Wall](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wall) or [with Bloodraven himself](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Cave_of_the_three-eyed_crow).

The slightly disappointing but very realistic answer would be that they are simply lost or hidden and have become irrelevant to the story.